# jQuery Validate plugin does not work with rules('add') method

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

I've a problem...
I'm working on a joomla custom search module for sobipro, which can search in a specific category, but can't search in its sub-categories.
For this reason i need to validate the form and set as "Required" the "sid_list1" select list class.
I'm trying to use the JQuery Validate Plugin, but it doesen't work for me.
This is how i set him, any idea?

```
<script text= type='text/javascript'> 
$("#XTspSearchForm132").validate(
{
    rules:
    {
        $('.sid_list1').each(function() {
    $(this).rules('add', {
        required: true,
        messages: {
            required:  "your custom message"
        }
    });
});
</script>

<form action="/index.php" method="post"
      id="XTspSearchForm132" >
    <div class="XTsearchhome">



<div class="XTSPSearch">
  <div></div>
  <div class="spspacer" style="clear:both;"></div>
  <div id="XTSPSearchForm">
    <div class="XTSPSearchCell1">
      <div class="XTSPSearchLabel">
        <strong>Search for: </strong>
      </div>
      <div class="XTSPSearchField"><input type="text" name="sp_search_for" size="20" value="visibile"  onblur="if (this.value=='') this.value='search...';" onfocus="if (this.value=='search...') this.value='';" class="XTSPSearchBox inputboxhome" id="XTSPSearchBox132" maxlength="20"/> </div>
    </div>
    <div class="XTSPSearchCell2">
      <div class="XTSPSearchField"><input type="submit" id="XTtop_button" name="search" value="Search" class="buttonhome" onclick="this.form.sp_search_for.focus();extSearchHelper132.extractFormValues();"/> </div>
    </div>

    <div class="XTSPSearchCell3">
      <div class="XTSPSearchLabel">
        <strong>Find entries that have: </strong>
      </div>
      <div class="XTSPSearchField"><span>
<!-- RadioButton 'spsearchphrase' Output -->
<input type="radio" name="spsearchphrase" id="XTspsearchphrase_all" value="all" checked="checked" />
<label for="XTspsearchphrase_all">All words</label>
<!-- RadioButton 'spsearchphrase' End -->
</span><span>
<!-- RadioButton 'spsearchphrase' Output -->
<input type="radio" name="spsearchphrase" id="XTspsearchphrase_any" value="any" />
<label for="XTspsearchphrase_any">Any words</label>
<!-- RadioButton 'spsearchphrase' End -->
</span><span>
<!-- RadioButton 'spsearchphrase' Output -->
<input type="radio" name="spsearchphrase" id="XTspsearchphrase_exact" value="exact" />
<label for="XTspsearchphrase_exact">Exact Phrase</label>
<!-- RadioButton 'spsearchphrase' End -->
</span> </div>
    </div>
    <div class="spspacer" style="clear:both; margin-bottom: 10px;"></div>
    <div class="spspacer" style="clear:both; min-height: 2px;"></div>
    <div id="XTSPExtSearch"><div class="XTSPSearchCell4"><div class="XTSPSearchLabel"><strong>Categories:</strong></div><div class="XTSPSearchField"><select class='sid_list1' name='to_sid_list_1321' id='extparent_1321' style='margin-top:4px;'><option style="" value="" selected="selected">- Seleziona categoria -</option><option style="" value="spc55" class="spc63" >Africa del Sud</option><option style="" value="spc56" class="spc63" >Nord America e Caraibi</option><option style="" value="spc57" class="spc63" >America Centrale</option><option style="" value="spc58" class="spc63" >Sud America</option><option style="" value="spc59" class="spc63" >Isole del Pacifico</option><option style="" value="spc60" class="spc63" >Oceano Indiano</option><option style="" value="spc61" class="spc63" >Penisola Arabica</option></select><select class='sid_list2' name='to_sid_list_1322' id='extparent_1322' style='margin-top:4px;'><option style="" value="" selected="selected">- Seleziona categoria -</option><option style="" value="spc62" class="spc55" >Botswana</option><option style="" value="spc64" class="spc55" >Mauritius e Seychelles</option><option style="" value="spc65" class="spc55" >Mozambico</option><option style="" value="spc66" class="spc55" >Namibia</option><option style="" value="spc67" class="spc55" >Zimbabwe e Zambia</option><option style="" value="spc68" class="spc55" >Sudafrica</option><option style="" value="spc69" class="spc56" >Anguilla</option><option style="" value="spc70" class="spc56" >Antigua e Barbados</option><option style="" value="spc71" class="spc56" >Aruba</option><option style="" value="spc72" class="spc56" >Bahamas</option><option style="" value="spc73" class="spc56" >Bermuda</option><option style="" value="spc74" class="spc56" >Giamaica</option><option style="" value="spc75" class="spc56" >Rep Dominicana</option><option style="" value="spc76" class="spc56" >St Lucia</option><option style="" value="spc77" class="spc56" >St Martin</option><option style="" value="spc78" class="spc56" >Turks and Caicos</option><option style="" value="spc79" class="spc56" >US &amp; British Virgin Islands</option><option style="" value="spc80" class="spc56" >Canada</option><option style="" value="spc81" class="spc56" >Canouan Island</option><option style="" value="spc82" class="spc56" >Stati Uniti</option><option style="" value="spc83" class="spc57" >Belize</option><option style="" value="spc84" class="spc57" >Costa Rica</option><option style="" value="spc85" class="spc57" >Guatemala</option><option style="" value="spc86" class="spc57" >Messico</option><option style="" value="spc87" class="spc57" >Panama</option><option style="" value="spc88" class="spc58" >Equador</option><option style="" value="spc89" class="spc58" >Perù</option><option style="" value="spc90" class="spc59" >Hawaii</option><option style="" value="spc91" class="spc59" >Polinesia Francese</option><option style="" value="spc92" class="spc60" >Seishelles</option><option style="" value="spc93" class="spc60" >Mauritius</option><option style="" value="spc94" class="spc61" >Dubai</option><option style="" value="spc95" class="spc61" >Oman</option></select></div></div><div class="spspacer" style="clear:both; margin-bottom: 10px;"></div>
      <div class="XTSPSearchCell5">
        <div class="XTSPSearchLabel">
          <strong>Prodotto: </strong>
        </div>
        <div class="XTSPSearchField"><select id="XTfield_prodotto" name="field_prodotto" id="XTfield_prodotto" class="XTSPSearchSelect" >
    <option value=""> --- Select Prodotto  --- </option>
    <option value="prodotto_option_12">Noleggio auto</option>
    <option value="prodotto_option_11">Escursioni</option>
    <option value="prodotto_option_10">Soggiorni Mare</option>
    <option value="prodotto_option_9">Tour in Auto</option>
    <option value="prodotto_option_8">Tour di Gruppo</option>
    <option value="prodotto_option_7">Minitour</option>
    <option value="prodotto_option_6">Noleggio moto</option>
    <option value="prodotto_option_5">Noleggio camper</option>
</select> </div>
      </div>
      <div class="spspacer" style="clear:both; margin-bottom: 10px;"></div>
      <div class="XTSPSearchCell6">
        <div class="XTSPSearchLabel">
          <strong>Paese: </strong>
        </div>
        <div class="XTSPSearchField"><select id="XTfield_paese" name="field_paese" id="XTfield_paese" class="XTSPSearchSelect" >
    <option value=""> --- Select Paese  --- </option>
    <optgroup label="Africa del Sud">
        <option value="paese_option_7">Botswana</option>
        <option value="paese_option_10">Mauritius e Seychelles</option>
        <option value="paese_option_9">Mozambico</option>
        <option value="paese_option_11">Nambia</option>
        <option value="paese_option_12">Sudafrica</option>
        <option value="paese_option_8">Zimbawe e Zambia</option>
    </optgroup>
    <optgroup label="America Centrale">
        <option value="paese_option_18">Belize</option>
        <option value="paese_option_17">Costarica</option>
        <option value="paese_option_16">Guatemala</option>
        <option value="paese_option_15">Messico</option>
        <option value="paese_option_14">Panama</option>
    </optgroup>
    <optgroup label="Nord America e Caraibi">
        <option value="paese_option_37">Anguilla</option>
        <option value="paese_option_36">Antigua e Barbados</option>
        <option value="paese_option_35">Aruba</option>
        <option value="paese_option_34">Bahamas</option>
        <option value="paese_option_33">Bermuda</option>
        <option value="paese_option_26">Canada</option>
        <option value="paese_option_25">Canouan Island</option>
        <option value="paese_option_32">Giamaica</option>
        <option value="paese_option_31">Rep Dominicana</option>
        <option value="paese_option_30">St Lucia</option>
        <option value="paese_option_29">St Martin</option>
        <option value="paese_option_24">Stati Uniti</option>
        <option value="paese_option_28">Turks and Caicos</option>
        <option value="paese_option_27">US &amp; British Virgin Islands</option>
    </optgroup>
    <optgroup label="Oceano Indiano">
        <option value="paese_option_178">Seishelles</option>
        <option value="paese_option_177">Mauritius</option>
    </optgroup>
    <optgroup label="Pacific Islands">
        <option value="paese_option_149">Hawaii</option>
        <option value="paese_option_148">Polinesia Francese</option>
    </optgroup>
    <optgroup label="Penisola Arabica">
        <option value="paese_option_182">Dubai</option>
        <option value="paese_option_181">Oman</option>
    </optgroup>
    <optgroup label="Sud America">
        <option value="paese_option_146">Equador</option>
        <option value="paese_option_145">Perù</option>
    </optgroup>
</select> </div>
      </div>
      <div class="spspacer" style="clear:both; margin-bottom: 10px;"></div>
      <div class="XTSPSearchCell7">
        <div class="XTSPSearchLabel">
          <strong>Stile di Viaggio: </strong>
        </div>
        <div class="XTSPSearchField"><select id="XTfield_temi" name="field_temi" id="XTfield_temi" class="temi SPSearchSelect">
    <option value=""> --- Select Stile di Viaggio  --- </option>
    <option value="stile_option_13">Luna di Miele</option>
    <option value="stile_option_12">Avventure</option>
    <option value="stile_option_11">Natura e Animali</option>
    <option value="stile_option_10">Deserto</option>
    <option value="stile_option_9">Cultura e Antiche Civiltà</option>
    <option value="stile_option_8">Spiaggia Mare e Relax</option>
    <option value="stile_option_7">Sott'Acqua</option>
    <option value="stile_option_6">On the Road</option>
    <option value="stile_option_5">Shopping nelle Grandi Città</option>
    <option value="stile_option_4">Mai più Soli</option>
    <option value="stile_option_3">Spa e Benessere</option>
    <option value="stile_option_2">Famiglie</option>
</select> </div>
      </div>
      <div class="spspacer" style="clear:both; margin-bottom: 10px;"></div>
      <div class="XTSPSearchCell8">
        <div class="XTSPSearchLabel">
          <strong>Cerca nelle offerte: </strong>
        </div>
        <div class="XTSPSearchField"><div id="XTfield_offerte">
<div ><span>
<!-- CheckBox 'field_offerte[]' Output -->
<input type="checkbox" name="field_offerte[]" id="XTfield_offerte_field_offerte_option_1" value="field_offerte_option_1" class="XTSPSearchChbx" />
<label for="XTfield_offerte_field_offerte_option_1">Sì</label>
<!-- CheckBox 'field_offerte[]' End -->
</span></div></div><div class="spspacer" style="clear:both;"></div> </div>
      </div>
      <div class="spspacer" style="clear:both; margin-bottom: 10px;"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="spspacer" style="clear:both;"></div>
  <div class="XTSPListing">
    <div class="XTSPEntriesListContainer"></div>
    <div class="spspacer" style="clear:both;"></div>
    <div class="spspacer" style="clear:both;"></div>
  </div>
</div>
<div>

<input type="hidden" id="XTSP_sid" name="sid" value="54"/>
<input type="hidden" id="XTSP_task" name="task" value="search.search"/>
<input type="hidden" id="XTSP_option" name="option" value="com_sobipro"/>

            <input type="hidden" id="sid_list132" name="sid_list" value=""/>
                    <input type="hidden" id="XTSP_Itemid" name="Itemid" value="101"/>
    </div></div>
</form>
```

Comment: Thank you for reply, but it doesn't work.
look at the website, are there any error?
http://www.provafabio.netsons.org

Comment: I did not see your comment until now because you didn't put it under my answer.  Yes, your original code was malformed and if you properly integrate my solution into your code, it will work.  You are supposed to apply some common sense, not just blindly copy from the jsFiddle.  The lines which contained comments `//for demo`, **are only for the jsFiddle demo** so you can _simulate_ the submit without an error.  Remove the entire `submitHandler` block from your code if you really want yours to submit!  (See the code out in the open of my answer)

Comment: **Look at your browser's error console.**  The very first error is `Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found) - jquery.js`.  This means, you're not even including the jquery file so nothing is going to work.  Nothing is here: [www.provafabio.netsons.org/components/com_sobipro/lib/js/jquery.js](http://www.provafabio.netsons.org/components/com_sobipro/lib/js/jquery.js)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot put the [`rules('add')`](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation/rules#.22add.22rules) method *inside* of [`.validate()`](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation/validate#options).  Only in special situations are you allowed to put a function inside of `.validate({rules:{...}})` ... this is not one of them.

`rules('add')` is a whole separate method, and as such, gets used independently from `.validate()`.  That's the whole point of having a separate method.  You use `.validate()` to initialize the form, and then you can use other methods to manipulate the plugin further.

Do it like this...

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    // initialize the plugin with .validate()
    $("#XTspSearchForm132").validate({
        // other rules and options
    });

    // use rules() method to add rules by class name
    $('.sid_list1').each(function () {
        $(this).rules('add', {
            required: true,
            messages: {
                required: "your custom message"
            }
        });
    });

});
```

**Working Demo:  http://jsfiddle.net/RtFKc/**

Comment: hi, I remove demo lines end enable the requested jquery, but no results for now

Comment: @user2043299, please study up on the topics of JavaScript and jQuery syntax.  You have a syntax error as per the browser's console.  Hint:  You forget to remove a `}`.  See my code, no, _study_ my code above... see the difference?

Comment: I don't mean to sound rude or come off the wrong way, but Stackoverflow is primarily meant [for "professional and enthusiast" programmers](http://stackoverflow.com/faq).  You are expected to have some basic programming skills beyond 'cut & paste', including the ability to pull up your browser console to see any JavaScript errors.

Comment: You don't sound rude, you write a true thing...
The error 404 on the jquery.js, is generated by an extension, which load the jquery library for the second time, so it cause conflict with the other one, loaded by the background module, I disabled it by changing name to the file to hide it.
I think the error displayed now:
Uncaught TypeError: Object #<HTMLDocument> has no method 'ready' 
is caused by "$" in the script, I've to change it in "jQuery".
I try and update discussion if it will be the correct way
Thanx

Comment: YEAH it works!
Thank you so much Sparky, I'll offer you a coffee if you pass in Italy! :)

Comment: @user2043299, You're welcome.  I'm glad you finally figured it out.

Comment: ...and if i want to add an other class? I can to that with input names, but with class I don't know

Comment: @user2043299, it's the same thing... see this [demo about classes](http://jsfiddle.net/uxUey/).  Also, [browse my answers about the Validate plugin](http://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=votes&q=user%3a594235%20%5bjquery-validate%5d) if you want to learn more.

Comment: it retrieves me error on call function, have i to call the second function if the first is validated? (We're talking about dependent select list)

Comment: @user2043299, I'm really not sure what you're asking.  Since this problem is solved, it would be easier for you to please create a whole new question for this new problem.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

In my case `$(this).rules('add', ...)` solve and works fine by call it inside `$(document).ready(...)`.