# Validate a couple of dependent select lists with plugin jquery validate

Tags: jquery-validate, call, selectlist

As the title said, I need to validate 2 dependent select lists with the jQuery Validator Plugin, to force website users to choose an option from all 2 fields (they have to become required fields).
If you see the html you can read a "disabled" tag on the second list, which will removed when user select one of the list1 option.
Here's the **simplyfied code of the form**

```
<form action="/index.php" method="post" id="XTspSearchForm132" >
<select class='sid_list1' name='to_sid_list_1321' id='extparent_1321' style='margin-top:4px;'><option style="" value="" selected="selected">- Seleziona categoria -</option><option style="" value="spc55" class="spc63" >Africa del Sud</option><option style="" value="spc56" class="spc63" >Nord America e Caraibi</option><option style="" value="spc57" class="spc63" >America Centrale</option><option style="" value="spc58" class="spc63" >Sud America</option><option style="" value="spc59" class="spc63" >Isole del Pacifico</option><option style="" value="spc60" class="spc63" >Oceano Indiano</option><option style="" value="spc61" class="spc63" >Penisola Arabica</option></select>
<select class='sid_list2' name='to_sid_list_1322' id='extparent_1322' style='margin-top:4px;'><option style="" value="" selected="selected" disabled="disabled">- Seleziona categoria -</option><option style="" value="spc62" class="spc55" >Botswana</option><option style="" value="spc64" class="spc55" >Mauritius e Seychelles</option><option style="" value="spc65" class="spc55" >Mozambico</option><option style="" value="spc66" class="spc55" >Namibia</option><option style="" value="spc67" class="spc55" >Zimbabwe e Zambia</option><option style="" value="spc68" class="spc55" >Sudafrica</option><option style="" value="spc69" class="spc56" >Anguilla</option><option style="" value="spc70" class="spc56" >Antigua e Barbados</option><option style="" value="spc71" class="spc56" >Aruba</option><option style="" value="spc72" class="spc56" >Bahamas</option><option style="" value="spc73" class="spc56" >Bermuda</option><option style="" value="spc74" class="spc56" >Giamaica</option><option style="" value="spc75" class="spc56" >Repubblica Dominicana</option><option style="" value="spc76" class="spc56" >St Lucia</option><option style="" value="spc77" class="spc56" >St Martin</option><option style="" value="spc78" class="spc56" >Turks and Caicos</option><option style="" value="spc79" class="spc56" >US &amp; British Virgin Islands</option><option style="" value="spc80" class="spc56" >Canada</option><option style="" value="spc81" class="spc56" >Canouan Island</option><option style="" value="spc82" class="spc56" >Stati Uniti</option><option style="" value="spc83" class="spc57" >Belize</option><option style="" value="spc84" class="spc57" >Costa Rica</option><option style="" value="spc85" class="spc57" >Guatemala</option><option style="" value="spc86" class="spc57" >Messico</option><option style="" value="spc87" class="spc57" >Panama</option><option style="" value="spc88" class="spc58" >Equador</option><option style="" value="spc89" class="spc58" >Perù</option><option style="" value="spc90" class="spc59" >Hawaii</option><option style="" value="spc91" class="spc59" >Polinesia Francese</option><option style="" value="spc92" class="spc60" >Seishelles</option><option style="" value="spc93" class="spc60" >Mauritius</option><option style="" value="spc94" class="spc61" >Dubai</option><option style="" value="spc95" class="spc61" >Oman</option></select>
<input type="submit" id="XTtop_button" name="search" value="Search" class="buttonhome" onclick="this.form.sp_search_for.focus();extSearchHelper132.extractFormValues();"/>
</form>
```

Removing of "disable" tag probably depends to this script, loaded by the form: http://www.provafabio.netsons.org/modules/mod_sobiextsearch/js/jquery.chained.min.js

Now I'm using this script, which works for the first, but not for the second...

```
<script text= type='text/javascript'> 
var $j = jQuery.noConflict();
$j(document).ready(function () {

    $j("#XTspSearchForm132").validate({
        // other rules and options,
    });

    $j('.sid_list1').each(function () {
        $j(this).rules('add', {
            required: true,
            messages: {
                required: "your custom message"
            }
        });
    });

    $j('.sid_list2').each(function () {
        $j(this).rules('add', {
            required: true,
            messages: {
                required: "your custom message"
            }
        });
    });


});
</script>
```

I need to find the syntax of action which activate the second list, to realize a script which works like this one jsfiddle.net/km6XE/ (sorry, can't post more of one link)

Here's the form in action: provafabio.netsons.org

Comment: -1.  sorry but you haven't cut this question down to the bare minimum to explain the problem, you have just cut and pasted a bunch of your code.  You have also included an external link that (for me when I tried it) didn't work

Comment: I see that the exact same code is included here - http://stackoverflow.com/q/14709361/678338

Comment: if you see the topic, you can read a suggestion to open a new one...

Comment: user2043299, yes, this is a new question, but @politus was making the point that you've simply dumped the entire page's code into this question too.  _Please_ condense this down into a concise example, just the **bare minimum** amount of code required to make a demo. Then explain clearly what you expect this code to do.  Right now, nobody wants to dig through all that code to create a custom answer.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is in your "other rules and options" part of your example that you haven't included, as there is nothing wrong with your form or your JavaScript code

The error you describe is often encountered when you have specified a rule for a method that doesn't exist - [have a look at this fiddle for an example](http://jsfiddle.net/Z7saz/1/)

eg. this will give you the error you are seeing

```
$('#myform').validate({
        rules: {
            field1: {
                non_existent_method: true
            }
        }
});
```

Comment: now the link is working (it was a temporary server problem...) as you can see, there aren't any other part of code (the form is the top left one), it works for the first select list, but not for the second

Comment: I helped the OP with his first question.  Now I'm wondering why/if he needs to use `rules('add')` in the first place.  Unless the form is dynamically changing, just declare the rules normally using `.validate()` or inline with `class`.

Comment: @user2043299, since it's dynamically changing, there's no point in calling `rules('add')` on DOM ready if those input elements don't yet exist.

Answer (score 0):

You do not use `rules('add')` within DOM ready if the `input` element does not yet exist.

This answer shows that when the user clicks a button one time, a new field called `newfield` is added to the `form` and then the [rules are added dynamically](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation/rules#.22add.22rules) to this new `input` field.

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    $('#myform').validate({ // initialize the plugin
        rules: {
            field1: {
                required: true,
                minlength: 5
            },
            field2: {
                required: true,
                minlength: 5
            }
        }
    });

    $('button#add').one('click', function () {
        var field = '<input type="text" name="newfield" /><br />';
        $('#myform').prepend(field);
        $('[name="newfield"]').rules("add", {
            required: true,
            messages: {
                required: "this new field is now required"
            }
        });
    });

});
```

**Demo:  http://jsfiddle.net/km6XE/**

You'll need to make sure your code creates a **unique** `name` for each new `input` or you'll break the Validate plugin.

Comment: so I've to start like this:`
var $j = jQuery.noConflict();
$j(document).ready(function () {

    $j("#<?php echo $searchformid; ?>").validate({
     rules: {
      $j('.sid_list1'): {
            required: true,
            }`

Comment: @user2043299: No, firstly, this comment section is not the best place to post code or have a lengthy discussion; please feel free to **append your original posting** with additional information.  Look at my code above to see the format for how rules are declared within `.validate()` versus how they're dynamically added with `rules('add')` method.

Comment: My problem is this: I've 2 select list and I've to define rules for class. Above they're input text, and they were called from name.
If I understand, I've to define rules for the first class, and after that I've to define the event which generate the second list, and add rules for its, right?

Comment: @user2043299, yes, I think so, but I'm having a really tough time following your comments.  Can you update your original posting to **only** contain the **minimal amount** of code required to duplicate this problem, along with a **very detailed** description about what you want it to do?  Thanks.

Comment: @user2043299, no, it's not ok.  That is the same jQuery code we've seen all along.  **Where is the form's HTML now?**  And we just need to see the **bare minimum** required to make a working jsFiddle.  We do not need to see all the HTML from your whole page.  Try to show us a "complete concise self-contained" example.  Otherwise, you should study my answer above.  It shows you two things... one, it shows you how to declare rules for elements that exist and two, it shows you how to create a new element and add a rule.

Answer (score 0):

> Quote OP:  "I need to understand: 1) how can i add rules to the first class
>   without using 'add' function 2) how can i add rules to a select list
>   which does not exist in DOM"

See the following:

> "1) how can i add rules to the first class without using 'add' function"

If you want to assign those rules to many elements at a time by using their `class`, using `rules('add')` is acceptable.  If you add rules by `name`, there are other ways.  Again, since you are targeting by `class`, using `rules('add')` is acceptable here.

> "2) how can i add rules to a select list which does not exist in DOM"

You **can not** add rules to something that does not exist yet in the DOM.

**Inside whatever function is used to create the element is where you'd place your `rules('add')`.**

**THIS IS JUST AN EXAMPLE:**

**IF** you use a button to add an input element, you'd put `rules('add')` inside the `click` handler function.  The same idea applies no matter how you add the new `input`.  Since we can't see that part of your code, I'm sticking with my generic example below:

```js
$('button#add').one('click', function () { // <-- WHATEVER FUNCTION YOU USE to add the new input

    // THIS is just SAMPLE code that adds a new input element
    var field = '<input type="text" name="newfield" /><br />';
    $('#myform').prepend(field);

    // NOW HERE, AFTER the new input is created, is where to add the rules.
    $('[name="newfield"]').rules("add", {
        required: true,
        messages: {
            required: "this new field is now required"
        }
    });

});  // <- end button#add click handler
```

**Working Demo:  http://jsfiddle.net/km6XE/**

Essentially this is the same as my [first answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14759567/594235).